# sql sub and grand total

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Is there a nice consise way to get grand totals here-- this query shows sub totals for each day, but how can I get the grand total of each sub total without a sub query or another query

also is there something better to use than compute sum?

```
SELECT loguser,logdate,logaction,logtime
FROM log WHERE loguser IN
('scott')   AND logdate  
BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-15'   
ORDER BY logdate DESC    
COMPUTE SUM(logtime) BY logdate
```

SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: What implementation of SQL?  SQL Server, Oracle, MySQL, PostgreSQL?

Comment: Google for 'sql compute' and it seems that [COMPUTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190452.aspx) is provided in MS SQL Server for backwards compatibility and there are preferred alternatives.

Comment: yep I saw that-- that's why I asked if there was something better, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with COMPUTE as you've used it, but this (or a variation on it) should work in most SQL dialects...

```
SELECT loguser,logdate,logaction,SUM(logtime)
FROM log WHERE loguser IN
('scott')   AND logdate  
BETWEEN '2011-06-01' AND '2011-06-15'
GROUP BY loguser,logdate,logaction WITH ROLLUP
ORDER BY logdate DESC
```

Comment: looks pretty good... any idea why there are 2 grand totals at the bottom, one with loguser & one NULL

Comment: is there a way to put text in place of the null result-- like "Sub Total:", "Grand Total:" ?

Comment: ROLLUP will, as it says, roll up all of the group by fields, from right to left.  Creating ever increasing levels of summation.  If you `ORDER BY loguser,logdate,logaction`, you'll see it more clearly.  (As an extra FYI, WITH CUBE will find every possible combination of summation, and so the order in the GROUP BY becomes mute.)

Comment: For replacing the NULLs with text, you have two choices.  ISNULL() will replace them just like it normally does.  But sometimes you can have NULLs in the fields already, and it be impossible to figure out which NULL is a 'real' NULL and which is the result of ROLLUP.  or such cse you can use `GROUPING(<field_name>)` which returns whether of not that field has been summed up, or is just a normal part of the GROUP BY.  That can then be used in a CASE statement...  `CASE WHEN GROUPING(loguser) THEN 'GRAND TOTAL:' ELSE loguser END`

Answer (score 0):

Better way to get grand total is to use front end..instead of query.

Comment: why, i'd say it is a "different" way

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look at using ROLLUP over COMPUTE as Dems suggests, but if what you want is 3 things returned- 1) the daily logtime data, 2) the daily subtotal; and, 3) the grand total (total of subtotals) then I think you will need to UNION a query that finds the first two like the one you have with a query that finds the grand total.

Comment: definently want to avoid union-- i though maybe you could stack COMPUTE SUM's to do it-- & yep it does give multiple result sets-- but one thing I was able to do was format each result

Comment: @scott K - I don't think you can stack the COMPUTEs.  That's why I suggested the UNION if you wanted 3 parts.  I could be wrong.  I don't think a UNION would be that big of a performance hit.  Hope you are able to figure this out.